# pip install tesserocr hangs during setup.py

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

Ubuntu installation gets stuck very early on. Current list of packages and confirmation that Tesseract and Leptonica seems to be installed correctly. Any clues appreciated?

```
(venv) ubuntu@ip$ pip install tesserocr
Collecting tesserocr
  Using cached
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/6d/4e81e041f33a4419e59edcb1dbdf3c
56e9393f60f5ef531381bd67a1339b/tesserocr-2.3.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: tesserocr
  Running setup.py install for tesserocr ... \

Package         Version
--------------- -------
click           6.7    
Cython          0.28.5 
dominate        2.3.1  
Flask           1.0.2  
Flask-Bootstrap 3.3.7.1
Flask-Login     0.4.1  
Flask-WTF       0.14.2 
ghostscript     0.6    
gunicorn        19.9.0 
itsdangerous    0.24   
Jinja2          2.10   
MarkupSafe      1.0    
Pillow          5.2.0  
pip             18.0   
pkg-resources   0.0.0  
setuptools      20.7.0 
visitor         0.1.3  
Werkzeug        0.14.1 
WTForms         2.2.1  
(venv) ubuntu@ip-172-26-9-100:~/apa$ tesseract -v
tesseract 3.04.01
leptonica-1.73
libgif 5.1.2 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.4.2) : libpng 1.2.54 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.
2.8 : libwebp 0.4.4 : libopenjp2 2.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved after rebooting the machine. Not sure why this worked, other than I'd installed a lot of packages to get to this stage, and maybe something required a restart to complete the installation? If anyone can explain the problem, I'd be interested to understand why that might be?